# How can I add two date strings in the format HH:MM:SS together?

Tags: php, date, datetime, format, hour

I am saving the variables in the format of HH:MM:SS.
I want to sum up several variables such as:

```
TotalTime += var1+var2
```

It gives me the result of 0,
whats the right format for getting the sum as HH:MM:SS?

Comment: Convert them to `DateInterval` and uses its methods for adding intervals.

Comment: Please show your current code which you have

Comment: It's unclear what do you exactly need but this could help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695797/sum-time-from-datetime/29765989#29765989](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695797/sum-time-from-datetime/29765989#29765989). Maybe this question is also duplicate.

Comment: So where are we with this question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just converted the first date into a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and the second date I converted into a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, which I then can [`add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) to the first date.

```
<?php

    $var1 = "12:23:01";
    $var2 = "05:22:45";

    $date = new DateTime($var1);
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", $var2);
    $interval = new DateInterval("PT" . $hours . "H" . $minutes . "M" . $seconds . "S");

    $date->add($interval);
    echo $date->format("H:i:s");

?>
```

output:

```
17:45:46
```